# Base64 to PNG with JS

Tags: javascript, base64, png

Do you guys know of a method to convert a base64 string to a PNG with javascript. I basically want to display it in a website.

Example string:

```
"imageData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAC9JREFUOI1jYaAyYKGdgYse/6fIpDhZRlQDqQRGDRw1cNTAUQPpbSC0PKOegVQCADCrA81JwUxoAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

Comment: You should check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968945/convert-base64-png-data-to-javascript-file-objects

Comment: hey @VinodSrivastav: i saw the entry before but unfortunately it does not answer my question as it only converts PNGs to file objects.

Comment: I figured it out. If this question is reopened, then I can answer my question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `document.getElementById()` to get the element and set the **src** to look like this:

```html
    <img id="dynImg" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

for example: this creates a small red dot

```js
    document.getElementById("dynImg").src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...";
```

**Example:**

```html
<img id="dynImg" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not you can use AJAX in Javascript library to load image

Use AJAX like below code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
         $("#mydiv").load("myfile.php");
});
```

Use this script file for library **[jquery-1.9.1.js](http://harikarank.com/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1.js)**

Below code did in php. call this in ajax. For getting in base64 image src.

```
<?php
$path= 'http://harikarank.com/harikarank/harikarank.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $base64;?>" />
```

Then store the base64 image in your folder using server side script. then call saved path in javascript