# How to convert base64 string into file object in Javascript which should work in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How to convert base64 string into file object in Javascript which should work in IE Browser

```
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl: any, filename: string) {
        var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        while (n--) {
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}
```

This is not working in IE browser edge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968945/convert-base64-png-data-to-javascript-file-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading lots of tutorials I find a conclusion that Blob is also treated as File and we can post Blob into formdata.

```
var base64data = window.localStorage.getItem("img").replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
        var bs = atob(base64data);
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bs.length);
        var ba = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < bs.length; i++) {
            ba[i] = bs.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var file = new Blob([ba], { type: "image/png" });
```

Comment: atob is deprecated now, here is what it says:

@deprecated — Use Buffer.from(data, 'base64') instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

This adds js compability into older browsers

Comment: Thank you jan ...But I am using Angular2. So is there any other way to do the same.

Comment: this didnt help?