# ANGULAR 4 Base64 Upload Component

Tags: angular, upload, base64, components, directive

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular 4. Where there is a requirement to send the base64 Image as one of the model member to the web api. Is there a Angular component or directive for the  that would bind the base64 to the said model?

Appreciate and Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can upload image and store it as base64 encoded.

In your `template` add this

```
<div class="image-upload">
    <img [src]="imageSrc" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px"/>
    <input name="imageUrl" type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="handleInputChange($event)" />
</div>
```

And this will handle your upload mechanism from `component`

```
  private imageSrc: string = '';

  handleInputChange(e) {
    var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
      alert('invalid format');
      return;
    }
    reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
    let reader = e.target;
    this.imageSrc = reader.result;
    console.log(this.imageSrc)
  }
```

You can also use this code to make a component to upload an image

Comment: can you tell how i can decode this base64 to back to file if i want

Comment: If you want it in server side (ie php) please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/7140626

And if you want to do it using javascript follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38936042/7140626

Answer (score 2):

To answer your exact question...

> Is there a Angular component or directive for the that would bind the base64 to the said model?

**No.** It's out of scope of Angular. You can [use common ways of encoding data into base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript).

You can then [create a control value accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659742/angular4-no-value-accessor-for-form-control/45660571#45660571) that would take care of conversion, to keep your code more DRY.

Answer (score 2):

```
imgBase64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCA..." //your image base64 data url

onSubmit(){
    const file = this.DataURIToBlob(this.imgBase64)
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', file, 'image.jpg')
    formData.append('profile_id', this.profile_id) //other param
    formData.append('path', 'temp/') //other param

    this.dataService.setProfileImage(formData). //send formData in body
}

DataURIToBlob(dataURI: string) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
    const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
        
    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)
      
        return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
}
```

Comment: `DataURIToBlob(dataURI: string)` function works great for converting a base64 image to Blob and save it in an Amazon S3 Bucket.