# How to create formData for image upload in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

I am trying to upload image (pmg/jpeg etc) which requires the formData to build first.

I am trying to upload base64 image to server.

I want to create formdata as below:-

## Desired formData:-

```
 ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileExtension";

    jpg
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContext";

    profile
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumbnailUpload";

    false
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumbnailExtension";

    png
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="be2081"
    Content-Type: UTF-8; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    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
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumbnail";

    [object Object]
    ----------MultipartData0.6961328157790669--
```

My code looks like:-

## .html

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" />
```

## .ts

```
 uploadFileToActivity() {
// sending file 
        this.user.postFile(this.imageUploadFinal).subscribe(result => {

        })
    }
    handleFileInput(event) {
        this.fileToUpload = <File>event.target.files[0];
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = e => (this.imageUploadFinal = reader.result,  this.uploadFileToActivity());
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        this.fileToUpload = btoa(binaryString);  // Converting binary string data.
        this.uploadFileToActivity();
    }
```

## .service.ts

```
postFile(fileToUpload){
        const endpoint = 'https://....;
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', fileToUpload, );  <====== formData
        return this.http.post(endpoint, formData )
    }
```

Comment: You can append those values to your formData instance

Comment: Can you please show me based on requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `Content-Type multipart/form-data` too

Like this

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

return this.http.post(url, formData, headers);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to get formData in desired format as I mentioned above. How to create one as I am missing something in formData and it is causing error,  when endpoint is called

Comment: Maybe you can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216410/angular-4-base64-upload-component)

Comment: Sorry, this does not help. There is a bug in my approach and its a question of specific issue.

Comment: @Mahi can you share your code for me so I can take a look ?

Comment: I have updated code already, which piece of code, I should update.