# How to convert 16bit raw data into png image to show in browser?

Tags: javascript, image, png, 16-bit, rawimage

I have 16 bit raw data as base64 string. Want to convert that into png image, based on depth 8,16,24.

```
// code to process 16bit buffer array
function process16bitBitmap(buffer, options = {}) {
const view = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer);
const out = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer.byteLength);
// set alpha channel
view.forEach((a, i) => out[(i * 4) + 3] = a);
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = options.width;
canvas.height = options.height;
const imgData = new ImageData(out, options.width, options.height);
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
// if you want to save a png version
document.body.appendChild(canvas);}
```

fiddle to reproduce the issue [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wa8pdvg/)

Facing hard time to correctly create a png file from 16 bit raw data.
16 bit image should looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the pixel format of the raw data? If not do you have what the final image is supposed to look like?

Comment: Pixel format is RGB and to draw on canvas it should be RGBA of 8bit. Also you can check the jsonData method in jsfiddle, there i have put the raw base64 which I am  trying to convert into png.

Comment: Is the raw data least or most significant byte first?

Answer (score 1):

### With javaScript Vanilla:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968945/convert-base64-png-data-to-javascript-file-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) but coundn't find a way to reproduce.

### With nodejs:

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/4e9864f182c053d7a51d) and it works fine. Also found [this](https://gist.github.com/caisah/e6a5eb413f607a2edb5d132226169218) but didn't work for me.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const base64ToPNG = (data) => {
    data = data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');

    fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'image.png'), data, 'base64', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}

var img = "YourImageHere...iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANwAAADcCAYAAAAbWs+...";

base64ToPNG(img)
```

If your objective is doing it with vanilla I don't know if I could help you, with node that way works, so probably you'll just need to figure how to adjust the depth.